# C Program Switch and If statement

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, playing-cards

So i am trying to create a C code program that will be given the shorthand notation for a playing card and will determine the formatted playing card.  Example
        Input: H 8
        Output: 8 of Hearts

```
    Input: C 14
    Output: Ace of Clubs
```

Rank: 2-10, 11 Jack, 12 Queen, 13 King, 14 Ace
Suit: C Clubs, D Diamonds, H Hearts, S Spades
But in the final stages of implementation i ran into a couple serious problems. The program runs fine when I enter like D 5 but enter D 12 will make it list queen then jack then 12 of diamonds.

Heres the code: http://pastebin.com/Tj4m6E2L
And heres the current EXE: http://www.mediafire.com/download/4fy4syga2aj8n2j

Thanks for any help you can provide. I am new to C code so keep it simple and stupid for my benefit.

Comment: provide your code here, its easier to find problems and answer

Comment: Edit to include what is your problem with your code, and what you have tried.  This isn't 'code review'

Comment: The spec in the code comments show an example input as `Input=5C` -- you have to read that in as a string, one time, rather than have two inputs, if it is really specified that way.

Comment: You need to read up on the `break` statement and then sprinkle these liberally throughout that huge sprawling `switch`. While you're doing that, try to think about how you might simplify your code - there's a huge amount of repetition and redundancy.

Comment: Ask yourself if you were to happen upon this question "is there is enough information to respond with anything helpful?"   Show your effort.  Point out the specific error you are seeing.  Ask specific question, i.e. what do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing crucial `break` statements in your `switch`, e.g.

```
switch(rank)
{
  case 14:
   {
   if(suite == 'H')
        printf("Your card is the Ace of Hearts!");
   else if(suite == 'C')
        printf("Your card is the Ace of Clubs!");
   else if(suite == 'D')
        printf("Your card is the Ace of Diamonds!");
   else
        printf("Your card is the Ace of Spades!");
   }
  // <<< NB: case 14 "falls through" to case 13 here !!!
  case 13:
    ...
```

Change this to:

```
switch(rank)
{
  case 14:
   {
   if(suite == 'H')
        printf("Your card is the Ace of Hearts!");
   else if(suite == 'C')
        printf("Your card is the Ace of Clubs!");
   else if(suite == 'D')
        printf("Your card is the Ace of Diamonds!");
   else
        printf("Your card is the Ace of Spades!");
   }
   break; // <<< FIX
  case 13:
    ...
```

Repeat for all the other missing `break` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should always put a `break;` statement at the end of every `case` in the `switch` statement. Without it, if a certain case is met, all the lines that appear after that case will be executed.

For example, the first case in your program should be written as followed:

```
case 14:
     { //not required
   if(suite == 'H')
        printf("Your card is the Ace of Hearts!");
   else if(suite == 'C')
        printf("Your card is the Ace of Clubs!");
   else if(suite == 'D')
        printf("Your card is the Ace of Diamonds!");
   else
        printf("Your card is the Ace of Spades!");
     } //not required
   break; //add this line
```

Also, you may omit the braces as they are not required.